# ARCore for older android devices

Tags: android, image, augmented-reality, arcore, surface

Is possible to run ARCore on older devices? 
I want to detect a vertical surface  and render 2D image from user gallery on it. 
Just it.

Maybe you have other libs for it?

Comment: Show your code efforts.

Comment: ARCore is blocked to some devices [link](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) and i want run it on other .

Answer (score 2):

For developing apps using ARCore you need at least Android 7.0 or later (even if you want to detect vertical planes). Some smartphones require Android 8.0 or newer versions. Here's a list of [supported](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) devices.

It's impossible to use ARCore on older devices. If we assume that you can use older devices – there are software and hardware issues you will run into. Older smartphones and tablets have weaker CPU/GPU, less RAM, and have no definite OS layers necessary for performing tasks for ARCore.

However, you can try [Vuforia Engine](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/vuforia-fusion-supported-devices.html) 'cause it still supports some older Android devices.

Comment: Thanks. are you know some other libs that can render something on wall?

Comment: Look for it here: https://thinkmobiles.com/blog/best-ar-sdk-review/. I think `#8 ARToolKit` is your choice.